# Why is the "house with two rooms" is a 2-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

We know that a plane is a two-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. But in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, the house with two rooms is a $2$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Why is that? Isn't it supposed to be a $3$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

[image]

Comment: What section/page are you on?

Comment: @florence Chapter 0 page 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is page 4 of Hatcher's book.

The "house" refers to the walls, ceiling and floor, not the air contained inside of it. Each of those locally looks like a plane, so the house itself locally (in most places) looks like a plane: 2-dimensional.